# Create UIButton inside Objective C method

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I am trying to create a `UIButton` in code, and this code is in some methods which will get called from some class.

Here is the method that creates the button

```
-(void)createButton
{
    NSLog(@"createButton");
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:@"Get Friends" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(loadTableView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];    
}
```

but it never appears in the view, what's wrong?

Edit: if I call this method from `viewDidLoad` then it works!

Edit 2: the method is in the ViewController class and I call it from MyFacebooDelegate class 
here is the call code from MyFacebooDelegate class:

```
 ViewController *m2 = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[m2 createButton];
```

Comment: Where are you calling it from when it fails?

Comment: And is it being called on the main thread?

Comment: I am calling this method from another class, but there is no errors appear, what are you meaning with the "main thread"

Comment: What do you mean that you are creating the code in another class? Please show us some other details. Mike D is asking if you are creating that button in a thread different than the main one. If so, don't do it!

Comment: My hunch is that you're calling this method before the ViewController's view has loaded -- can you check if self.view is nil?

Comment: No its not null, also this method is in the same view that appears at first time

Answer (score 1):

May be your view is not loaded from Nib yet at the moment. If you created view by instantiating

```
[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"someNibName" bundle:nil];
```

than view controller will be created and start to load view from Nib asynchronously. So, if `UIViewController` is instantiated, that does not mean `UIView` is. So, that's why your button work when created from `-viewDidLoad:` callback.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new `ViewController` using `ViewController *m2 = [[ViewController alloc] init];` it is not the same `ViewController` that is handling the screen.

Instead of allocating a `ViewController`, you should be using the one that's created when the application starts.

Comment: thnx ,,, so how I can call the method in a way that will draw my button?

Comment: Get a reference to your existing view controller and use it as the target for `createButton`.  How to do that depends entirely on how the first `ViewController` is loaded in your app (root controller? owned by a navigation controller?)  ...? .